# Email from specific IP is not being received on server. Possibly malicious admin

Tags: debian, sendmail, exim

A few days ago I requested SSH access to our old server where we currently host our email. We are in the process of moving over to a new host. Ever since requesting the access from the admin, emails which are being sent from the new server, eg. wordpress/cs-cart/prestashop, are not being delivered to email accounts on the old server. The email accounts on the old server are otherwise working fine, and sending email from the new server to accounts hosted elsewhere works fine as well.

Is it possible the old admin, being upset about losing a client, set up some kind of block? Looking through .bash_history, it has obviously recently been cleared.

Comment: What do you mean by "not being delivered"?

Comment: Your emails will be delivered to one server or the other. Per-user MX records aren't a thing.

Comment: My first reaction is "Huh?". Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: On the new server there are no errors in the mail logs, in fact all the emails are marked as completed. On the old server the emails do not appear at all in the inbox. Otherwise sending emails to the old server via Gmail for example works fine. This problem did not exist until requesting root access.

Comment: If emails are being delivered to your new server, that means your MX records have been modified to point to the new server, which means that no email will be delivered to your old server.

Comment: The new server is not configured for receiving so we have not touched the MX records yet. We want emails to be received by the old server which are coming from the new server.

Comment: You need to work through this with your "old admin".

Comment: Understand. I am not looking to fix this, as we are moving email accounts to the new server today anyway. My question: is it possible the old admin could have set up some kind of email block for a specific IP? And if so how can I identify this? How could he have done this? As I said bash history is clean which might mean he is covering something up.

Comment: Can it be you create SPAM? If the new server is not in the MX, then the old server may just think it is an unauthorized server and throw away the emails. I am sure my servers would - you are not allowed to send emails just from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, of course that's possible. Talk with the vendor. The fact that the .bash_history is clear doesn't mean a thing. Perhaps he had deleted your user account and then had to re-create it when you requested SSH access.

Comment: TomTom There is no reason for having the new server in the MX as the sending and receiving domain are completely different and have nothing to do with each other. Of course it could be marked as SPAM but spamassassin is not installed. 

EEAA A new user was not created for me, I was given root access. Unfortunately it was not disabled for SSH. The root users history was deleted recently and recreated with a few commands left by the old user greping for an email address I have never seen. The bash history for HIS username, which is still on the server, has had the .bash_history file deleted.

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules to see if any specific IP's smtp routes are blocked?

Comment: Yes, there are no rules set. Which is why I am having a hard time figuring out what might have caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had begun setting up the old email addresses on the new server in order to get ready for the transfer. The local config was taking precedence over MX records. Problem solved and I feel guilty for considering our old admin may have had something to do with it.